# Exclude or include the particular row from the mat-table view

Tags: angular, filter, pipe

I have a material data table like `id`  `title` `description`
The data source for my `mat-table` is represented by `dataSource$: Observable<Thing[]>`

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource$ | async">
...
<mat-table>
```

Based on a dropdown I want to be able to show all the data(the way it works at the moment) but also to hide the items that have `description` empty and way around hide the items that have `description` not empty.

I think I have to do that through the custom pipe? or use a `.filter()` on my observable?
Any thoughts how to aproach that best?

**UPDATE:**

I am trying to use `.filter()` but got an issue, have no data displayed with that:

```
dataSource$ = originalDataSource$.filter((item: any) => item.description == null)
```

thoughts?

Comment: As you said, `filter` your `dataSource$`

Comment: @Vega I have 3 conditions, `show all`, `show only with description` and `show only without descirption` so that might not work.

Comment: @Vega also in case of `ngif` i have to copy the ngif statement all across each `<ng-container>` of my `mat-table`  which is not cool.

Comment: @Vega any more details on how to aproach `ng-template` here?

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to maintain original `dataSource$` separately like `originalDataSource$`. Write change event on dropdown like `(change)="onChange($event.target.value)"` and filter your data in that function like

```
onChange(value){  
 dataSource$ = originalDataSource$.filter(m =>{ your logic/conditions })
}
```

Comment: I am tryiing that aproach but have an issue, can you see the updated sectoin?

Comment: Lol. You are filtering null data. Your condition should be like `filter((item: any) => item.description !== null)`

Comment: how would you add 3 conditions in to filter 1) to skip the filter, 2) to filter if description is empty 3) to filter if description not empty?

Comment: You can make function and put multiple conditions. Refer this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter