# Apply filter to datasource to send specific data to table

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource, angular7, mat-table

I was trying to add a conditional filter to the datasource before it is loaded to mat-table, thus only those data within specific status "open" can be shown on that table. But I have no idea how can I do that.

I tried the solution from [Exclude or include the particular row from the mat-table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935597/exclude-or-include-the-particular-row-from-the-mat-table-view) , but it returns a TS2349 error. Also I tried ng-if as I always did on other tables, but it only hide the values and leave me a lot of empty rows. Below is the code with error.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.afs.collection<any>('Projects').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
// TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'String' has no compatible call signatures.
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data).filter(data => data.status === 'open');
// error ends
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    })
  }
```

And this is the html part:

```html
    <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [trackBy]="trackByUid" class="animate" (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">

      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold"> ID </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                {{ hacker.id }}
          </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="publishedDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold"> Published Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                {{ hacker.publishedDate }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold"> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                {{ hacker.name }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>


      <ng-container matColumnDef="type">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold"> Type </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                {{ hacker.type }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="dueDate">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold; color:#fff"> Due Date </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                {{ hacker.dueDate }}
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="edit">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="font-weight: bold"> Edit </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let hacker">
                  <button mat-raised-button  color="primary" (click)="openDialog(hacker)">Edit</button>
          </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="animate"></mat-row>
    </mat-table>
      <mat-paginator [length]="100"
                     [pageSize]="10"
                     [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
      </mat-paginator>
```

I am expecting that I can prevent those data with "data.status !== 'open'" being shown on my table. (Now it is displaying everything before  Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: If you log out `data` from the `valueChanges`, is it in the format you expect?

Comment: @Phix Could you tell me how to log out data? I was thinking to find a way to modify the dataSource though...

Comment: Just use `console.log` and make sure it's formatted the way you are expecting.

Comment: @Phix Yes, that's exactly the way I am looking for.

Comment: @Phix But I still didn't find the way to wipe out those without correct data value yet.

Comment: Without a reproducible example there's not much we can do. Can you make one on stackblitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to filter the data first and **then** initialize the `MatTableDataSource`, not do both at the same time. The below snippet should solve your problem.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.afs.collection<any>('Projects').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {
    const filteredData = data.filter(d => d.status === 'open');   
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredData);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  });
}
```

> I made a small
>   [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-default-table-vmfmph?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   here to show you how you can easily filter the data before displaying
>   it in a table.

Answer (score -1):

If you wana filtering data easily,
**Pipe** is a good class to apply filter to data in html:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
return items.filter( it => {
      return it.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

Then use it on array in html, inside for:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let c of characters | filter : searchText">
    {{c}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

for more info on this: [Create a Search Pipe to Dynamically Filter results](https://codeburst.io/create-a-search-pipe-to-dynamically-filter-results-with-angular-4-21fd3a5bec5c)